# Oracle Crush после запуска - ORA-00600

Tags: oracle

После запуска Oracle происходит crush.  Не понимаю в чём проблемма. Вот логи ([а также ссылка на файл с логами](http://dropmefiles.com/M8b5d)):

```
15:55:31 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109786):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656211
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.287.16, scn 0.3211656215
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656282
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.340.16, scn 0.3211656283
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 53 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:55:41 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109787):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 269 to scn 3211656191
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.271.16, scn 0.3211656195
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 269 to scn 3211656285
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.342.16, scn 0.3211656286
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 54 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:55:52 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109788):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656215
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.289.16, scn 0.3211656218
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656295
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.351.16, scn 0.3211656296
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 55 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:02 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109789):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 265 to scn 3211656188
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.268.16, scn 0.3211656190
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 265 to scn 3211656299
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.353.16, scn 0.3211656300
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 56 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:12 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109790):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 269 to scn 3211656191
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.271.16, scn 0.3211656195
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 269 to scn 3211656304
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.356.16, scn 0.3211656305
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 57 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:22 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109791):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656215
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.289.16, scn 0.3211656218
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656310
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.359.16, scn 0.3211656311
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 58 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:32 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109792):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656211
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.287.16, scn 0.3211656215
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656315
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.362.16, scn 0.3211656316
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 59 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:42 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109793):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 276 to scn 3211656203
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.280.16, scn 0.3211656206
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 276 to scn 3211656318
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.364.16, scn 0.3211656319
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 60 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:56:53 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109794):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656215
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.289.16, scn 0.3211656218
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 287 to scn 3211656327
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.371.16, scn 0.3211656328
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 61 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:57:03 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109795):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 265 to scn 3211656188
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.268.16, scn 0.3211656190
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 265 to scn 3211656334
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.372.16, scn 0.3211656335
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 62 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 15:57:13 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109796):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656211
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.287.16, scn 0.3211656215
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 282 to scn 3211656338
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.373.16, scn 0.3211656339
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 63 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:02:23 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109797):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 392 to scn 3211656455
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.398.16, scn 0.3211656456
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 392 to scn 3211656455
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.398.16, scn 0.3211656456
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing logging scn->time mapping.
SMON encountered 64 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:07:24 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109798):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 399 to scn 3211656564
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.403.16, scn 0.3211656565
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 399 to scn 3211656564
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.403.16, scn 0.3211656565
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing logging scn->time mapping.
SMON encountered 65 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:12:26 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109799):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 404 to scn 3211656672
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.439.16, scn 0.3211656673
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 404 to scn 3211656672
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.439.16, scn 0.3211656673
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 66 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109800):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 439 to scn 3211656674
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.440.16, scn 0.3211656675
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 439 to scn 3211656674
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.440.16, scn 0.3211656675
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 67 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109801):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 399 to scn 3211656564
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.403.16, scn 0.3211656566
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 399 to scn 3211656675
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.441.16, scn 0.3211656676
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 68 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109802):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 441 to scn 3211656676
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.443.16, scn 0.3211656677
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 441 to scn 3211656676
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.443.16, scn 0.3211656677
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 69 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109803):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 404 to scn 3211656672
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.439.16, scn 0.3211656674
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 404 to scn 3211656682
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.449.16, scn 0.3211656683
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 70 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:12:41 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109804):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 439 to scn 3211656674
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.440.16, scn 0.3211656675
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 439 to scn 3211656686
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.450.16, scn 0.3211656687
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 71 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:12:51 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109805):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 453 to scn 3211656693
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.458.16, scn 0.3211656694
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 453 to scn 3211656693
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.458.16, scn 0.3211656694
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 72 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:13:01 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109806):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 441 to scn 3211656676
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.443.16, scn 0.3211656677
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 441 to scn 3211656698
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.461.16, scn 0.3211656699
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing flushing of monitored table stats.
SMON encountered 73 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
Mon Aug 14 16:18:11 2017
Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc  (incident=109807):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4193], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 471 to scn 3211656802
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.475.16, scn 0.3211656803
Block recovery from logseq 177443, block 471 to scn 3211656802
Recovery of Online Redo Log: Thread 1 Group 3 Seq 177443 Reading mem 0
  Mem# 0: /oradata1/hpsm/redo03.log
Block recovery completed at rba 177443.475.16, scn 0.3211656803
Non-fatal internal error happenned while SMON was doing logging scn->time mapping.
SMON encountered 74 out of maximum 100 non-fatal internal errors.
```

Comment: вы бы приложили лог ошибки сюда

Comment: Выложил. посмотри плиз

Comment: Произошла внутренняя ошибка. Вам предлагают создать инцидент в оракле поддержке. В `/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/hpsm/hpsm/trace/hpsm_smon_4438.trc` подробнее об ошибке.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь, эта проблема лечится путём пересоздания табличных пространств UNDO.

Comment: ORA-00600 это общее сообщение о внутренней ошибке. И ваш вопрос, и также ответ, дают мало информации о её причинах, что делает этот топик не совсем полезным для других участников сообщества.

Comment: Если же вас интересует более полное решение данной задачи, вы можете прейти по ссылке ..   https://shanojkumar.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/ora-00600-how-to-recover-and-open-the-database-if-the-archive-log-required-for-recovery-is-missing/